# Render formula for plotting in LaTeX

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I am constructing a thermodynamic diagram. The basic structure is a x axis with temperatures in Celsius, and an y axis with pressure in hPa in logarithmic scale.
Then I need to add some lines giving the following formula:
:[image]

Here `Φ` is the next expected temperature (x axis), `T` is the starting temperature of each line in x axis, `p0` is the basic pressure, which usually has a constant value of 1000. `p` is the next pressure (y axis), and `k`  is a constant, `0.286`.
So for 10° the formula would be something like x = 10(1000/y)^0.286.

My interpretation of this diagram is this:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ymode=log,
      ymin=95,
      ymax=1100,
      y dir=reverse,
      xmin=-95,
      xmax=45,
      ylabel=p (hPa),
      xlabel=T,
      grid=both,
      ytick={100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000},
      width=15cm,
      height=15cm,
      decoration={name=none},
      log ticks with fixed point,
    ]
    \foreach \T in {-90,-80,-70,-60,-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40} {
        \addplot [blue, domain=-90:40] {\T * (1000/y)^0.286};
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which returns this error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots ex
pected to sample a line, not a mesh. Please use the [mesh] option combined with
 [samples y>0] and [domain y!=0:0] to indicate a twodimensional input domain.
```

And if I follow the advice with:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ymode=log,
      ymin=95,
      ymax=1100,
      y dir=reverse,
      xmin=-95,
      xmax=45,
      ylabel=p (hPa),
      xlabel=T,
      grid=both,
      ytick={100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000},
      width=15cm,
      height=15cm,
      decoration={name=none},
      log ticks with fixed point,
    ]
    \foreach \T in {-90,-80,-70,-60,-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40} {
        \addplot [blue, mesh, samples y > 0, domain y!=0:0] {\T * (1000/y)^0.286};
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/samples y > 0' and I am g
oing to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I'm pretty stuck there. Any help will be welcome.

EDIT:

---

@AndreyL proposes rearranging the formula to express `p` in terms of `theta` with `\addplot [blue, domain=-90:40] {1000*(\T/x)^(1/0.286)};`.
The problem with this is that is rendering a completely different diagram, see the image below.

[image]

Comment: You may express `p` in terms of `theta`: `p=p0*(T/theta)^(1/k)`, and plot the following functions: `\addplot [blue, domain=-90:40] {1000*(\T/x)^(1/0.286)};`

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndreyL. I actually tried that, but did not use neither the domain nor the parenthesis for the exponent: `\addplot [blue] {1000*(\T/x)^1/0.286};`.
The issue is that this is not rendering the expected plot. I-ll update the question with an example.

Comment: The default variable in PGFPlots is `x`, so you get an error when using `y`. `mesh` is a 2D mesh in 3D space. -not at all what you want here. "[samples y>0] and [domain y!=0:0]" is *not* options - it is telling you to set `samples y` to something positive and not to have a empty y domain.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is more physics than a LaTeX question...

After conversion from Celsius to Kelvin, I have similar plots. I hope now it looks correct.

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ymode=log,
      ymin=95,
      ymax=1100,
      y dir=reverse,
      xmin=-95,
      xmax=45,
      ylabel=p (hPa),
      xlabel=T,
      grid=both,
      ytick={100,200,...,1000},
      width=15cm,
      height=15cm,
      decoration={name=none},
      log ticks with fixed point,
    ]
    \foreach \T in {-90,-80,...,150} {
        \addplot [blue, domain=-90:40] {1000*((273+x)/(273+\T))^(1/0.286)};
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Thruth is that this question was previously posted on physics.stackexchange.com and closed as LaTeX related.

Comment: Anyway, your diagram is correct, lines cross x y coordinates in same points. But now there is is some issue related to x or y axis that makes the lines different. I'm wondering what it is.

Comment: @EmileC, my guess is that your P-T diagram is incorrect; it shows straight lines, but adiabats don't.